# Как спарсить json в локальную базу данных?

Tags: android, база-данных, json, парсер

Надо спарсить json в любую локальную базу данных. Очень много
Прочитал очень много ответов на stackoverflow про то как спарсить json (искал уже хоть во что-то), но примеры jsona попадались самые простые, где названия полей повторялись  ( типа "name", "age", "city" ).
Json (делал его не я) выглядит примерно так:
{ Note [txt,log,nnn], media [mp3,wav,ogg,arm] и еще таких же 20 }
Пожалуйста,не кидайтесь в меня камнями я просто пытаюсь разобраться.
Буду рад помощи!

Comment: Ну вот и считывай каждый объект и свойство отдельно или создай большой класс на c#/

Comment: А почему нужно сохранять данные в БД? Может быть, хранить этот json на файловой системе?

Comment: @DmitryTaipov хорошая идея. Но вот как это реализовать на java ?

Comment: @VladDen Java JSON API: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html
Другие библиотеки обсуждаются, например, тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java